# Mediaelement.js - getting NaNs with IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, mediaelement.js

On a mediaelement.js audio player I'm getting `NaN` on the progress bar and in the 'duration' indicator, but only when viewed in IE 11, in Firefox 26 everything is okay. This seems to imply that it's not a server issue but other reports I've seen say that it is.

Anyone have any ideas, and if it is likely to be a server issue what is it that I need to look at (Apache server)?

The following code from @BiscuitBaker will reproduce this issue:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
   $('video,audio').mediaelementplayer({
   audioWidth: 440,
   audioHeight: 30,
   // The file contains an audio watermark, so I've set the volume to 0 as I don't want this to be seen as self promotion.
   startVolume: 0 
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Standard mediaelement.js files, unmodified -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://beta.musicvine.net/wp-content/themes/theMusicVine/library/js/mediaelement/mediaelementplayer.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script src="http://beta.musicvine.net/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <audio controls src="http://beta.musicvine.net/wp-content/uploads/edd/2015/02/joyful-moments-adi-goldstein-preview.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having this problem too - in my case, the progress bar works correctly with very small mp3s, but seems to fail and produce NaN on anything bigger than a few MB.

Comment: Could the OP or @BiscuitBaker provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I'll give the OP a little time to reply and post one myself if needed. There's not a whole lot that could go into an MCVE though, I'm using the bog-standard implementation from the mediaelement.js website.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Sadly my edit got rejected, so a JSFiddle will have to do: http://jsfiddle.net/e8fpdg6s/1/

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be caused by an issue in Internet Explorer, where if the server does not respond with a `Content-Length` header, the `duration` property of the `audio` element is `Infinity`. You can see this by running the following code in developer tools console.

```
document.querySelector('audio').duration
```

Here is a screenshot of the response headers for you server.

[image: headers no content-length]

However, if I substitute the audio URL with one from a server that responds with the `Content-Length` header, such as this one, it works correctly.

```
https://archive.org/download/TESTTEST_174/asdfasdfasdfdfdszadfdsa.mp3
```

Screenshot of headers for the archive.org file.

[image: headers with content-length]

I've also double-checked by serving your file off my local server, and it worked when the `Content-Length` is supplied.

So your problem is apparently a server configuration issue. In fact, all response headers for static files on your website lack the `Content-Length` header. I don't know what would cause an Apache server to not include this header, perhaps a `mod_headers` rule, but that's the cause of your issue.

Comment: This was the problem! Thanks for your incredibly detailed answer. The culprit was gzip - turning this off reinstated the header.